# How to compare date string variable in C# with datetime field in sql query

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I have the following code,and I am trying to compare The date string with date time,but I can't get it to work.This does not output any rows.

```
DataTable tbl3 = dii.SelectGeneric("select * from widget_messages  where convert(datetime, m_date) ='" + String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy}", DateUsed) + "'");
```

Both datetimes are formatted exactly the same.Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you run the exact query into the database yourself?

Comment: the best fromat for sql 'yyyy-MM-dd'

Comment: @Arran - I've run the query with the date instead of DateUsed,but i still get no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting the `m_date` to `datetime` but `DateUsed` remains a string.

You should either compare them as strings, like this

```
DataTable tbl3 = dii.SelectGeneric("select * from widget_messages  where m_date ='" + String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy}", DateUsed) + "'");
```

or as datetimes, like this:

```
DataTable tbl3 = dii.SelectGeneric("select * from widget_messages  where convert(datetime, m_date) = convert(datetime,'" + String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy}", DateUsed) + "')");
```

EDIT: On SQL Server 2005 try this:

```
DataTable tbl3 = dii.SelectGeneric("select * from widget_messages  where abs(datediff(day,convert(datetime, m_date), convert(datetime,'" + String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy}", DateUsed) + "'))) = 0");
```

Comment: Thank you, @dasblinkenlight,still no results.I print out the date from database and the date from date used,and they are the same,but still no results.

Comment: @user1657214 Since you are using only the date portion, try converting to `date` rather than to `datetime`, like this: `DataTable tbl3 = dii.SelectGeneric("select * from widget_messages  where convert(date, m_date) = convert(date,'" + String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy}", DateUsed) + "')");`

Comment: Just tried than but i get this: Type date is not a defined system type

Comment: yep,that seems to be the case.

Comment: @user1657214 See the edit, `datediff` should work for sql server 2005.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight- Thank you for these great responses,@dasblinkenlight,that seems to have it fixed.Thanks again!

Comment: @user1657214 You are welcome! If you are not looking for an improved answer, you may want to accept this one by clicking the checkmark outline next to it. This will indicate to others that the solution has worked for you, and earn you a brand-new badge on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If m_date field is Date/DateTime type then following code will work fine.

```
DataTable tbl3 = dii.SelectGeneric("select * from widget_messages  where convert(varchar, m_date, 12) ='" + String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", DateUsed) + "'");
```